# Page title show "page not found" on wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i made a couple of php pages and integrated them into wordpress.
The first page is fine, but the second one show "page not found" on the title when it is loaded.
You can find the first page here:
http://www.stefanovirgulti.it/spese.php
then click on "Aggiungi Negozio" to go to second page.

code of first page:

```
(suppressed wordpress template code)
//if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
if ( true ){
    $index=linkBuilder("Aggiungi Negozio",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?p=1");
    $appPath="./moneym/";
    //$page=$_GET["p"];
    switch ($_GET["p"])
    {
            case 1:   
                $page="negozi.php";
            break;
            default:   
                echo "this is the first page<br>";
                echo $index;
            break;
    } 
    if ($page != "") include $appPath.$page;
}
else {
    echo "This is a private page.<br>";
}
function linkBuilder($name,$path){
    return sprintf("<a href=\"%s\">%s</a> ",$path,$name);
}
(suppressed wordpress template code)
```

The code of the second page contains only an echo.

How do i fix this?

PS: the second page works, but if you check the title page, it says "page not found" and i can't change that, this is my problem.

Comment: but i can see your second page too...same as first but written one day this page will do something
This is the second page.

Comment: i know, the second page works, but if you check the title page, it say "page not found" and i can't change that, this is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I found the "page custom template" functionality. I just made a template with all my code, then used it as template for a wp static page. 
I have done the custom template starting from page.php of my current template, took off the code that handles the content, and replace it with my php/sql stuff.
I have made a new page inside wp and used this custom template.
In this way i have a page that does what i want, but act as a real wp page, i can even add it to menus and apply whatever plugin to it. I left the title funcionality so i can change the title of my cutom page from wp admin.

Comment: It still doesnt solve the original "Page not found" error, but uses a different approach to running alternate php code

Answer (score 1):

How did you create these pages? Without looking at your header.php file I'll assume your using some sort of default code to get the page title. To create new pages in wordpress you need to create them in the backend admin panel. if your just loading in files, the wordpress enviroment will see this as a page that doesn't exist.

Comment: But using the back-end admin panel i can't use my own php code to access to my own database, the code that i didn't show is the code of page.php, ripped out of the part that gets the actual page content, and filled with the code i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

THe reason for this is that one of your included phps includes a check for wordpress environment and displays that title when the condition is satisfied.

The solution is to use php to output "" tags before the included file is loaded.